# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MyTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

I added a new table called JobFieldMapping in my database, and set a field as a primary key, and the IDENTITY (1,1). I update the .edmx file.
So, all should be work well, but on the savechanges() I got the error:

> *Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'JobFieldMapping' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.*

this is strange because I set nothing for the primary key field, in my code:

```
db.JobFieldMappings.Add(new JobFieldMapping { 
            FKID = tempID, 
            FieldName = "test", 
            FieldTitle = "test" 
        });
db.SaveChanges();
```

these are the properties for the PK field:

[image]

And this is the xml for the table

```
<EntityType Name="JobFieldMapping">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="JobFieldMappingID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="JobFieldMappingID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="FKID " Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="FieldName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="500" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="FieldTitle" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="500" Nullable="false" />
 </EntityType>
```

I tried to update the .edmx file more times, delete and regenerate it, but I got always the same error.

Comment: What does the resulting SQL look like? (take a look with the SQL Profiler)

Comment: @tschmit007 the identity_insert have to be off, in this way the PK field will be automatically incremented